# Let G be an abelian group where every element has finite order. If $c \in G$ has the largest order in G, then the order of every element divides |c|

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does anyone have an intuitive explanation for this result? My textbook uses a proof by contradiction. But it just doesn't come logically to me why this holds. What would go wrong if, for example, |a|=3 and |b|=4, where b is the largest order element?

Comment: In an abelian group, the order of $a+b$ is always the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$ (prove it!). So if $\lvert a \rvert = 3$ and $\lvert b \rvert = 4$, then $\lvert a + b \rvert = 12$, and so it is not possible that $b$ is an element of largest order in this case.